# How to rotate full page with tcpdf?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library to write a custom size label with background image and multiple text blocks on it.

The user when sees the preview on screen of the PDF it should show in horizontal, but for printing, I need the full page rotated -90 degrees.

How can I just rotate the whole page for printing version without having to move anything?

Answer (score 3):

Basically:

In my case I've already had to use a new document format for the special sizes my document required.

So I've duplicated that format, created one for Landscape and one for Portrait.

Then based on the $preview variable, if previewing I'm rendering the normal landscape document, but if not previewing, I'm using the Portrait format and orientation and also starting the transformation and rotating everything on page.

Hope this helps someone I've found no other "quick" way to accomplish this kind of full-page rotation.

```
<?php

// #1 get the preview attribute from 
// the form that was submitted from the user
$preview=  isset($_POST['preview'])?(int)$_POST['preview']:0;

// load TCPDF for CodeIgniter as a library
$this->load->library('Pdf');

// #2 set default orientation and format
$orientation='L';
$format='MAKE-L';

// #3 if not previewing, switch orientation and format to portrait
if (!$preview) {
  $orientation='P';
  $format='MAKE-P';
}

// create new pdf object 
// (same as doing new TCPDF(), it is just the CodeIgniter wrapper)
$pdf = new Pdf($orientation, 'mm', $format, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);

$pdf->AddPage($orientation, $format);

// #4 if not previewing, start transformation 
// and rotate everything before inserting any content
if (!$preview) {

  // Start Transformation
  $pdf->StartTransform();

  // Rotate counter-clockwise centered by (x,y)
  $pdf->Rotate(-90, 70, 70); // <-- TODO: test this very well because 70 and 70 was just guessing, there is no math behind that so not sure if it will work always

}

// put your content here, 
// for example set font and add a text
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 7, '', true);
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, 25.4, 2, 'lot number', 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
/// end content

// #5 if not in preview mode, finish the transformation
if (!$preview) {
  // Stop Transformation
  $pdf->StopTransform();
}

$pdf->Output('example.pdf', 'I');

/**
 * Last but very important note:
 * I have added my formats in tcpdf/includes/tcpdf_static.php file.
 * >> MAKE-L for Landscape
 * >> MAKE-P for Portrait
 */

 public static $page_formats = array(

        // Make
        'MAKE-L'                     => array( 396.850,  425.196), // = (  h 140 x w 150 ) mm

        // Make
        'MAKE-P'                     => array( 425.196, 396.850  ), // = (  h 140 x w 150 ) mm

        // .. rest of formats here ../
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

The [setPageFormat()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa389d4419c77510dc3998f0af78d8a00) method should do the job. You also can pass the parameter to the $format parameter of [AddPage()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a5171e20b366b74523709d84c349c1ced):

```
$pdf->AddPage($orientation, ['format' => $format, 'Rotate' => -90]);
```